# Does "easily-going" exist?

Tags: compound-adjectives

I'm studying English compound word patterns and "easily-going" is mentioned as an example of a compound adjective formed by an ADVERB + PRESENT PARTICIPLE. But it sounds too odd to me. I've done a quick search on the Internet and couldn't find any information about that. Would someone be so kind to shed some light on this? Thank you.

Comment: The adverb construction is better with a past participle: *easily made* or *easily done*. An adjective is better with the present participle: *hard-working* and *easy living*.

Comment: Please add the vital information of _where you found this_: a link and attribution. . CGEL, OED, or 'A School Grammar for the 1950s'?  It makes a **huge** difference. _And what do the respectable free online dictionaries (Lexico, CED, AHD, M-W, Collins, Macmillan ... Wiktionary?) say?_ Do they list it? _basic research is necessary on ELU._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth sorry for that. I don't know if this adjective is a self-invention of the anonymous author, or if it has been extracted from one of the sources cited as a bibliography at the end. The thing is I can't find it in dictionaries. This is the link to the text: https://www.oposinet.com/temario-de-ingles-secundaria/temario-2-ingles-secundaria/topic-10-the-lexicon-characteristics-of-word-formation-in-english-prefixation-suffixation-composition/

Comment: Please add which dictionaries you've found it isn't in to the question. And does it appear on Google? If so, are there many hits?

Comment: I have voted to close as the OP has not provided an example of *easily-going* as a compound.

Comment: Since there are no results of any kind that shows this structure as a compound adjective, and it does not look familiar to any of you, I deduced that the author meant "easy-going", but made a typo. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

*Easily going* is not a common colocation, but shows up on Google NGram, e.g.:

“Look, you're a badass player, and this is easily going to be the best season we've ever had, so we owe you.” (John Goode) and other books.

Or did I miss the question?

Comment: OP asks about the validity of the compound _easily-going_ as a variant of _easy-going_. The example you give is of the adverb _easily_ used within '... this is going to be the best ...'.